# How many Disney princesses end up with older men?

Tags: disney

Disney princesses are often quite young.

- **Snow White**: 14
- **Jasmine**: 14/15
- **Ariel**: 16
- **Aurora**: 16
- **Mulan**: 16
- **Merida**: 16
- **Belle**: 17

It seems like they often end up with older men. For example Aladdin has been various listed as being either 18 or 21. Many of these films end with the princess either engaged or married or at least in a "true love happy ever after" relationship.

Am I imagining this or do a lot of Disney princesses end up this way?

Comment: Just nitpicking: but is merida in a romantic relationship? as far as i recall, the romance in "Brave" was cut.

Comment: @BestGuess I didn't mean to imply that she was in a relationship, merely young.

Comment: I mean, this would be fairly normal in reality, especially for the upper class. I wouldn't even call a four year age gap as them marrying "older men".

Comment: I was going to ask something slightly different but realized that this baseline needs to be established first. Some of the stories are more problematic than other... Like Ariel who marries literally the first man she ever meets and then murders her aunt, or Jasmine (a child) who marries the adult man who tricked her into starting the relationship by pretending to be a prince.

Comment: How do you know their ages? They kind of strike me as "young adult" age - other than Sleeping Beauty whose age is part of the story.

Comment: @colmde Wikipedia and a google search.

Comment: @user - Her aunt? Who, Ursula? I thought she was just some random sea witch.

Comment: @Obie2.0 seems unconfirmed, was originally going to be the case but explicit mention of it was removed from the script. In any case she ended up murdering her.

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR: At least 6, probably 7, and possibly as many as 9.**

---

Going through the [official list of Disney Princesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Princess), from the top:

- **Snow White: Yes.** As you stated, she's 14 (15 by the end of the story) and according to production notes, Prince Florian is intended to be 18.
- **Cinderella: Unknown.** She's 19, older than most Disney Princesses, but I can't find an age for Prince Charming.
- **Aurora: Yes.** She's 16, and while I can't find an age for Prince Philip either, he met Aurora shortly after her birth and was already a young boy by then, so he's a few years older than her.
- **Ariel: Yes.** She's 16, and according to the film's novelisation, Prince Eric is 18.
- **Belle: No.** [She's 20 at youngest, and possibly older.](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/life/entertainthis/2016/05/10/beauty-and-the-beast-anniversary/84172242/) The Beast is 20 for most of the film and turns 21 right at the end, when the last petal falls (it's fated to do so on his 21st birthday). So it's possible Belle is actually *older* than him.
- **Jasmine: Yes.** She's 15, and Aladdin is 18 - although he was initially planned to be as young as thirteen before they aged him up.
- **Pocahontas: No.** While she does fall in love with John Smith, he travels back to England at the end of the film and they do not pursue a romantic relationship.
- **Mulan: Most likely.** Mulan is 16. I can't find an age for Shang but, given that he's already a captain in the army, he is probably older than that.
- **Tiana: Unknown.** She is apparently 19 (there's a sequel book about Naveen trying to find a 20th birthday present for her), but I can't find an age for Prince Naveen.
- **Rapunzel: Yes.** She's 18, and Flynn Rider is *26*, the largest age gap between a Disney Princess and her love interest.
- **Merida: No.** She doesn't fall in love with anyone.
- **Moana: No.** She doesn't fall in love with anyone.
- **Raya: No.** She doesn't fall in love with anyone.

Elsa and Anna aren't *officially* Disney Princesses, but for completion's sake:

- **Anna: Yes.** She's 18, and Kristoff is 21.
- **Elsa: No.** She doesn't fall in love with anyone.

Comment: I'm surprised they even have ages for these characters! I always just assumed their ages were kind of free-floating.

Comment: So am I. I particularly wasn't expecting many of the princes to have ages.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about a follow up question as to which of the marriages are legal, but as the time period and/or location are often difficult to place in the real world it might not be possible to determine.

Comment: Naveen is stated to be twenty in one of the tie-in books, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Early concept art for Li Shang has him as 23, but he's very different in the early images.